# Confusion defining the Main-Class in ant for bundling a jar

Tags: java, ant, jar, classpath, mechanicalturk

I'm trying to construct a jar file using the Amazon Mechanical Turk API.  The SDK comes with a helloworld file that I'm trying to jar up as a sanity check - it is located here:

http://aws.amazon.com/code/SDKs/695

After setting everything up, I'm able to use ant to build and execute correctly, using the supplied build.xml file.

```
bash-3.2$ ant helloworld
ant helloworld
Buildfile: /Users/astorer/Work/dtingley/java-aws-mturk-1.2.2/build.xml

compile-sample:
     [echo] Compiling the sample java source files...
    [javac] /Users/astorer/Work/dtingley/java-aws-mturk-1.2.2/build.xml:252: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds

helloworld:
     [echo] Running the Hello World sample application...
     [java] Got account balance: 10000.00
     [java] Created HIT: 2RB2D5NQYN5F41KJ2IKYPNCW2H3A60
     [java] You may see your HIT with HITTypeId '22R58B727M0IHQ4HZEXYISVF4XCWBC' here: 
     [java] http://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/preview?groupId=22R58B727M0IHQ4HZEXYISVF4XCWBC
     [java] Success.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 11 seconds
```

I want the helloworld to be executable by someone else without needing to install the libraries.  It seems like the "correct" way to do this is to construct a jar from within ant.

My understanding is that I need to include:

- the necessary libraries, build from the sdk itself (and provided as a .jar)
- the built helloworld class file
- the manifest attribute specifying the main class to run

I don't know if I need to include anything else.  I know that there is a big, complicated classpath at runtime, and that I can specify the classpath on the command line, but I suspect hard coding the classpath will prevent me from distributing the .jar file, which is the entire point.

Here is the build.xml snippet for the jar:

```
  <target name="hellojar" depends="helloworld" description="Creates Jar of helloworld" >
    <jar destfile="helloworld.jar">
      <fileset file="${sdk.jar}" />
      <fileset dir="${sample.classes.dir}/helloworld/" />
      <fileset dir="."/>
      <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="MTurkHelloWorld" />
      </manifest>
    </jar>
  </target>
```

This builds.  When I run the jar, it crashes, however:

```
bash-3.2$ java -jar helloworld.jar 
java -jar helloworld.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MTurkHelloWorld (wrong name: helloworld/MTurkHelloWorld)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

This makes sense, because my MTurkHelloWorld is actually in the helloworld package.  Thus, I should change to:

```
  <manifest>
    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="helloworld.MTurkHelloWorld" />
  </manifest>
```

This builds successfully.  When I run it:

```
bash-3.2$ java -jar helloworld.jar 
java -jar helloworld.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: helloworld/MTurkHelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: helloworld.MTurkHelloWorld
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

We can investigate the files within the jar:

```
jar tf helloworld.jar | grep hello
build/private/classes/samples/helloworld/
samples/helloworld/
build/private/classes/samples/helloworld/MTurkHelloWorld.class
samples/helloworld/MTurkHelloWorld.java
```

Which suggests that maybe if the classpath were set to build/private/classes/samples/ it would work properly:

```
<attribute name="Class-Path" value="build/private/classes/samples/helloworld" />
```

This leads to an identical error.  I think there is something pretty fundamental that I'm missing here, and I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your package-folder have to start directly, you can't put them in any sub-directory in the jar file:

It would have to look like this:

```
helloworld/
helloworld/MTurkHelloWorld.class
```

Your [jar-task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) would have to look like this:

```
<jar destfile="helloworld.jar" basedir="${sample.classes.dir}">>
  <manifest>
    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="MTurkHelloWorld" />
  </manifest>
</jar>
```

The basedir is the source of your compiled packages.
With `<fileset />` you just add normal files.

Furthermore, you can't put external libs into jar files. They have to be in the same folder as the jar, in the `java classpath` or in a folder specified by the [`classpath-attribute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jar/jar.html) of the manifest.
Or you could use the [one jar task](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=introduction&file=intro), to include the classes into your jar.

Comment: what do you think is the best practice in this situation?  To make a jar (using one jar), or to just give instructions to tell folks to install the package itself and make ant tasks to run things?

Comment: @alexplanation instructions can always be misread. I'd suggest(if you give it directly to end-users) either a zip-file(that contains everything and just has to be unpacked). Or the onejar approach.