# Cannot compile Apache Netbeans project using Ant from command line

Tags: java, netbeans, command-line, ant

I was trying to set up compiling a Netbeans project from the command line. The project uses Ant as a build system, so I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007573/compile-netbeans-project-from-command-line-by-using-ant) and followed it. The program compiles fine, however, when trying to run the program using `java -jar file.jar` it terminates, saying `no main manifest attribute`.

Furthermore, I would also like to know if there is a way to run the ant command for a specific file, like one would in netbeans when right-clicking and selecting `Run file`, as when running `ant jar` there is no opportunity to select a file.

Comment: Can you please share your build files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confusion defining the Main-Class in ant for bundling a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347364/confusion-defining-the-main-class-in-ant-for-bundling-a-jar)